# Como usar un constructor en React Js

Tags: reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo a usar React Js haciendo una calculadora y me quede atorado en la parte del constructor

El tutorial dice de que la clase constructor va en donde estan los botones, y va asi

```
constructor() { 
super(); 

// set our default state 
this.state = { 
  question: '', 
  answer: ''
} 

// Bind our handleClick method (sets 'this' explicitly 
// to refer to this componenent) We did this because 'this' 
// would refer to the source of the click events 
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); 
 }
```

Coloque ese codigo en donde va la calculadora, y tira un error diciendo "UNREACABLE CODE DETECTED" o dice que falta un ";"

Este es el tutorial que estoy siguiendo
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-calculator-app-adding-functionality/?ref=rp

Esto es lo que tengo en donde esta la calculadora por ahora

```
import './css/App.css';
import Button from './operations/button.js';


function App() {
  return (
<div className="calculator card">

<input type="text" className="calculator-screen z-depth-1" value="0" disabled />

<div className="calculator-keys">

  <Button type="Button" label={'+'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="+" name="operator"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'-'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="-" name="operator"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'*'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="*" name="operator"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'/'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="/" name="operator"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'root'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="square_root"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'cube root'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="cube_root"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'^'} className="operator btn btn-info" value="power_of"></Button>

  <Button type="Button" label={'7'} value="7" className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'8'} value="8" className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'9'} value="9" className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>


  <Button type="Button" label={'4'} value="4" className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'5'} className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'6'} className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>


  <Button type="Button" label={'1'} className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'2'} className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'3'} className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>


  <Button type="Button" label={'0'} value="0" className="btn btn-light waves-effect"></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'.'} className="decimal function btn btn-secondary" value="."></Button>
  <Button type="Button" label={'AC'} className="all-clear function" variant="danger" value="all-clear"></Button>

  <Button type="Button" label={'='} className="equal-sign operator btn btn-default" value="="></Button>

</div>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Comparte el código del componente `Button`, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el tutorial, se están usando stateful components y tu estas usando stateless components.

Los stateless components no tienen constructor, para manejar propiedades, lo puedes hacer mediante hooks (useState).

Aquí se explica bastante bien:
https://medium.com/@cgcrutch18/stateful-vs-stateless-react-components-13f647f7fc4

Para que te funcione como en el tutorial el componente debería ser stateful:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
```